# How to obtain principal component % variance explained in R? prcomp() and preProcess() comparison

Tags: r, pca, r-caret

I know that PCA can be conducted with the `prcomp()` function in base R, or with the `preProcess()` function in the `caret` package, amongst others.

Firstly, am I right in saying that if we just use the default settings for operations of type `prcomp(<SOME_MATRIX>)` or `preProcess(<SOME_MATRIX>, method = "pca")`, then the only difference in our results is that `prcomp()` does not centre and scale the data before conducting PCA, and preProcess() does? Therefore, do `prcomp(scale(<SOME_MATRIX>))` and `preProcess(<SOME_MATRIX>, method = "pca")` output the same thing?

Secondly, and more importantly, how can we obtain the % variance explained by each PC from the output of either `prcomp()` or `preProcess()`? From both of these outputs I can see things like the means, standard deviations or rotations, but I think these refer just to the 'old' variables. Where is the information about the 'new' PCs and how much variance they account for?

This might come in useful if, for example, I am using `preProcess(<SOME_MATRIX>, method = "pca", thresh = 0.8)` and this returns 6 PCs, but I find that the first 5 PCs explain a total of 79.5% of the variance. Then I might be inclined not to include all 6 PCs.

Comment: prcomp does center, but does not scale. You can always use `predict(preProcess(<some matrix>, method = 'pca'))` to get the result from preProcess

Comment: Thanks for the centering and scaling clarification, @Oliver. I was aware of using `predict(preProcess())` to get the results, but this doesn't tell me how much variance each PC explains, e.g. PC1 accounts for 27% of the variance, PC2 accounts for 19%, etc. Do you know where I can find this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your first question has already been answered, here the answer to your second question for `prcomp`. We can get the % variance explained by each PC by calling `summary`:

```
df <- iris[1:4]
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)
summ <- summary(pca_res)
summ

#Importance of components:
#                          PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4
#Standard deviation     1.7084 0.9560 0.38309 0.14393
#Proportion of Variance 0.7296 0.2285 0.03669 0.00518
#Cumulative Proportion  0.7296 0.9581 0.99482 1.00000

summ$importance[2,]
# PC1     PC2     PC3     PC4 
#0.72962 0.22851 0.03669 0.00518
```

From what I know this information is not available when using the `caret` package (see issue discussed [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/193)):

```
mod <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "knn",
                            preProc = c("center", "scale", "pca"))
str(mod$preProcess) 


List of 22
 $ dim              : int [1:2] 150 4
 $ bc               : NULL
 $ yj               : NULL
 $ et               : NULL
 $ invHyperbolicSine: NULL
 $ mean             : Named num [1:4] 5.84 3.06 3.76 1.2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ std              : Named num [1:4] 0.828 0.436 1.765 0.762
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ ranges           : NULL
 $ rotation         : num [1:4, 1:2] 0.521 -0.269 0.58 0.565 -0.377 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "PC1" "PC2"
 $ method           :List of 4
  ..$ center: chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..$ scale : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..$ pca   : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
  ..$ ignore: chr(0) 
 $ thresh           : num 0.95
 $ pcaComp          : NULL
 $ numComp          : num 2
 $ ica              : NULL
 $ wildcards        :List of 2
  ..$ PCA: chr(0) 
  ..$ ICA: chr(0) 
 $ k                : num 5
 $ knnSummary       :function (x, ...)  
 $ bagImp           : NULL
 $ median           : NULL
 $ data             : NULL
 $ rangeBounds      : num [1:2] 0 1
 $ call             : chr "scrubed"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "preProcess"
```

Comment: Thank you @Dominik! That seems simple enough and I really should have tried `summary()` as a first resort. I tried `summary()` on the `preProcess(method = "pca")` object too but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe someone else will know how to get PC % variance explained from those objects.

Comment: You're welcome! See updated answer, to my knowledge this information is not available when using the caret package.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have checked out the link. Firstly, I think the initial proposition there is wrong as for `PCA.1 <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)`, `PCA.1$sdev / sum(PCA.1$sdev)` does not equal the % variance explained `summary(PCA.1)$importance[2,]`, it would have to be `PCA.1$sdev^2 / sum((PCA.1$sdev)^2)`. Secondly, that `trace` object would be really helpful! But I guess since standard deviations are available in the `preProcess(method = "pca")` object then we can just do that calculation ourselves, although this is not ideal.